# Circulo dinâmico utilizando somente css e javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Estou tentando desenvolver um circulo dinâmico utilizando *somente* css e javascript, a principio não quero utilizar nenhuma biblioteca e não posso utilizar o canvas do html.

Minha ideia é poder definir o tamanho do circulo da seguinte forma: o primeiro clique do mouse ira definir o centro do circulo e o seguinte ira definir o raio. Isso é possível realizar?!

Meu código hoje:

```
 #circulo{ 
  background: #666;
  border-radius:100%;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
}

<!-- html -->
<div id="circulo"></div>
```

Estou com dificuldade em criar o javascript, alguém pode me dar algum exemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível:

```js
//Primeiro definimos as variaveis

//para sabermos se é o primeiro ou segundo clique
var click = false;

//posições x e y do primeiro clique
var c1x = 0;
var c1y = 0;

//posições x e y do segundo clique
var c2x = 0;
var c2y = 0;

//evento para quando clicam na pagina
document.onclick = function(e) {
    if(click == false) {
        //é a primeira vez que clica, vamos mudar a variavel para true
        click = true;
  
        //Atribuimos os valores às variaveis criadas antes
        c1x = e.clientX;
        c1y = e.clientY;
    } else {
        //é a segunda vez que clica, vamos voltar a colocar false
        click = false;
  
        //Atribuimos os valores às variaveis criadas antes
        c2x = e.clientX;
        c2y = e.clientY;
  
        //Como é o segundo clique, vamos desenhar o circulo
        circulo();
    }
}

function circulo() {
    //Primeiro fazemos a matematica para descobrir a distancia
    //entre o primeiro e o segundo clique
    //usando as variaveis declaradas antes
    
    var cx3 = c2x - c1x;
    cx3 = cx3 * cx3;
 
    var cy3 = c2y - c1y;
    cy3 = cy3 * cy3;
 
    //Depois de calcular a distancia, multiplicamos por 2
    //Para saber o diametro para usar como largura e altura do circulo
    var dis = Math.sqrt(cx3 + cy3) * 2;
 
    //Vamos "buscar" o circulo
    var cir = document.getElementById('circulo');
 
    //Definimos a sua posição para o primeiro clique
    //Retiramos metade da distancia para o circulo ficar no meio
    cir.style.top = (c1y - dis / 2) + 'px';
    cir.style.left = (c1x - dis / 2) + 'px';
 
    //E finalmente, damos a largura e altura ao circulo
    cir.style.width = dis + 'px';
    cir.style.height = dis + 'px';
}
```

```css
/*
position: absolute;
    para colocarmos o circulo em qualquer lugar da pagina
border-radius: 100%;
    para ser um circulo
*/
#circulo {
    position: absolute;
    background: #666;
    border-radius:100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- o circulo -->
<div id="circulo"></div>
```

Comment: Sim, vou editar a resposta